# Programming Techniques/Style for avoiding large switch/if blocks in C?

Tags: c, coding-style

Was just a quick question to see if there are different ways you code something similar when it comes to evaluating conditional statements/control flow.

For example:

- If Statements
- Switch Statements

Is there any tidier way to do these as I have basically the option of `If (value == X) { // do X }` and `Switch(value) { case X: ...`

When doing this with over 100 values is there any data driven approach that could be taken or any different evaluation methods that would tidy up the code?

Comment: this question is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry, is there anyway to move the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your values are integers and are not sparse sometimes it can be convenient to use a lookup table (both for data and for code - in this last case you'd use function pointers and is often called a jump table, which is incidentally what the compiler often does with `switch` blocks); if the alternative is checking the possible values one by one, the performance jumps from O(N) to O(1).

Also, for non-integer data, hash tables can be used. How convenient they are depends from case to case.